# Conditional text binding

Tags: extjs, extjs5

If i want to add a condition on text then how to do it?

For example :

> ```
>   {
>     text: 'Status', dataIndex: 'status'                
>    },
> ```

Here dataIndex is returning Status as "Completed" or "In-Progress". In some case it will return "null".

In case of "null", how to bind text as "Completed" ?

One way would be get data as "Completed" for null value from Database it self.

Is there any way i can do it in extjs?

> ```
>  if(dataIndex('status') == null)
>        text='Completed'
> ```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Use a column renderer.

Comment: Or a default value on the field definition in the model (if you're using one)

Comment: The main difference between these two approaches will be clearly visible if you apply a sorter or grouper on your grid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the way

```
   {
      text: 'Status', dataIndex: 'status',
      renderer: function(value){
               if(value === null){
                 return "Completed";
                }
               return value;
      }              
  }
```

Comment: Thank You. This is what i am looking for.